# How to calculate maximum increase in column value over any 24 hour period?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing lab tests for a collection of patients:

[image]

For each patient, I want to calculate the maximum increase in the lab value over any 24 hour period. I'm looking for a nice way to do this using Pandas. In the above example, the `CHARTIME` column are datetime objects (not necessarily in sorted order) and the `VALUE` column is the lab test I'm interested in (assume all units are the same). For `SUBJECT_ID = 3` in the above example, the increase in lab test value for each of the times given above can be seen below, and the maximum increase over any 24 period would be 0.2.

```
BASELINE            | INCREASE (24hr)
--------------------+----------------
2101-10-13 03:00:00 |  0.1
2101-10-13 15:47:00 | -0.2
2101-10-14 03:00:00 |  0.0
2101-10-15 03:30:00 |  0.2
2101-10-15 12:15:00 |  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the increases/decreases using `df.VALUE.diff()`. You can then find the maximum increase using either `df.INCREASE.max()` (for just finding the max value) or using `df.loc[df.INCREASE.idxmax()]` (for showing the entire row where the increase in the greatest).

Comment: I don't think you understand the question.  This does nothing to take the 24 hour period part of the question into account.  It also does not account for more than one SUBJECT_ID.